# can't install node-sass node.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0xB8790

Tags: c++, node.js, node-gyp, node-sass

I can't install node-sass.
I have installed the python2.7 and Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools,when I tried to compiling with VS2015 but bombed out much earlier with what appears to be missing header file errors.

#### My Environment

NPM version :v4.2.0

Node version :v7.10.0

Node Process:
{ http_parser: '2.7.0',
node: '7.10.0',
v8: '5.5.372.43',
uv: '1.11.0',
zlib: '1.2.11',
ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
modules: '51',
openssl: '1.0.2k',
icu: '58.2',
unicode: '9.0',
cldr: '30.0.3',
tz: '2016j' }

Node Platform :win32 win10

Node architecture: x64

node-sass version :Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'

npm node-sass versions (``):without

#### Errors:

```
npm i --save-dev node-sass
....
....
  Release\obj\binding\win_delay_load_hook.obj
  "D:\Project\GitRepositorys\awesome-TPC\node_modules\node-sass\build\Release\libsass.lib"
C:\Users\Administrator\.node-gyp\7.10.0\x64\node.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0xB8790 [D:\Project\ GitRepositorys\awesome-TPC\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.vcxproj]


gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (D:\Project\GitRepositorys\awesome-TPC\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:194:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Project\\GitRepositorys\\awesome-TPC\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Project\GitRepositorys\awesome-TPC\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v7.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 13):

You can try this too : https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/issues/272#issuecomment-339242933

`After spending 10+ hours and trying random solutions / things, I deleted C:\Users\UserName\.node-gyp folder and did npm i to resolve dependencies, which worked for me.`

It worked for me.

Comment: The rebuild of node-sass got stuck while downloading `node.lib`, so I killed the process. I started getting the same LNK1107 error. This solution worked for me as well.

Comment: Thx, I lost an afternoon on this ! If I could I would offer you a beer !

Comment: You can ! If you go to Paris :P

Comment: I would upvote this a 100 times if I could. Thanks!

Comment: Really, great. Thank you. Still working in 2022!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it use other method,

I updated npm and node to last edition。

download the node-sass releases https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

and install the local **.node

```
npm install node-sass sass_binary_path=C:/node-sass/darwin-x64-48_binding.node
it will be ok.
```

node-sass